# Vagrant sshのコマンドで反応がない。(ログインができません)

Tags: centos, vagrant, ssh

ターミナルでVagrant upでVagrantを起動済なのですが
その後、Vagrant sshコマンドでログインができません。

具体的には

```
    appletoma:centos7 toma$ vagrant ssh
    appletoma:centos7 toma$
```

となっておりlocal@hostに切り替わりません。

自分で調べた所、[ここのリンク](https://qiita.com/k-shimoji/items/abff44020bb3b2d065fe)にありますように

```
ssh -i 鍵のパス -p ホスト側のポート ゲスト側のユーザー名@ゲスト側のipアドレス
```

というコマンドで入れる可能性があるそうなのですが、この

```
鍵のパス -p ホスト側のポート ゲスト側のユーザー名@ゲスト側のipアドレス
```

の確認方法がわかりません。

これは自分のPC（MAC）のどこを確認すればよろしいでしょうか？

**追記（リンク先にあるコマンドを試したけど変化なし）**

```
appletoma:centos7 toma$ ssh -i /Users/toma/MyVagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
appletoma:centos7 toma$
```

Answer (score 1):

yukihaneさんへのコメントから、
起動後にIPアドレスを変更。プロセスの再起動なしにvagrant sshを利用したということでしょうか。
であれば、vagrant sshは効かなくなりそうですね。（想定する接続先がssh待ち受けしなくなるので）

vagrantとかいわゆるプロビジョニングツールも含めてこの種のツールは
ツールが設定できる項目はツール側にゆだねる。逆にOSにログインして変更しないってのがお約束なのだと思います。IPアドレスを変更したいのであればVagrantファイルで定義するのが定石かと。。

あとリンクの話ですが、利用しているコマンドにポート番号が指定されています。これはお使いの環境ごとに（vagrantファイルの定義ごとに）異なる値になるので、そのままコピペでは動作しないかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

通常なら[`vagrant ssh-config`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh_config.html)コマンドで出力できます。

例えば次のような出力になるはずです。リンク先で説明されている日本語名称と対応付けてみます:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1 <- ゲスト側のipアドレス
  User vagrant <- ゲスト側のユーザー名
  Port 2222 <- ホスト側のポート
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /.../.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key <- 鍵のパス
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

ただ、(質問文に書かれている情報が少ないので確証はないですが)リンク先の事象とは異なるように思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみましたがやっぱり変わりませんね。。（追記しました）実はこれの前に下記リンクに従ってIPアドレスの設定をしたのですが、これがまずかったのでしょうか？（この作業をする前はログインできていました）https://qiita.com/Kosei-Yoshida/items/3c1ed5bca95b836fa128